# Imagemagick gif and overlaying png image

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a [GIF animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN6W6.gif) with unknown size and a [PNG 600x400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAiVp.png) with transparent elements. How can I get a [GIF like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OyP8.png) with 600x400, cropping GIF  and working animation by Imagemagick?

Comment: You could tell us what Operating System you use...

Comment: Untested, off the top of my head `convert original.gif -coalesce -gravity center -crop 600x400+0+0\! -draw "image srcover 0,0 600,400 yourImage.png" result.gif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Imagemagick, you need to do a coalesce on the gif (to fill out the full frames) and -layers composite to combine the animated gif with a static image. Using Imagemagick 6.9.10.9 Q16 Mac OSX, it would be:

```
convert JN6W6.gif -coalesce -resize 600x400 null: PAiVp.png -gravity center -layers composite -layers optimize JN6W6_PAiVp_1.gif
```

[modified by resize only](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/layers_composite/JN6W6_PAiVp_1.gif)

If you want it simply cropped to 600x400, then

```
convert JN6W6.gif -coalesce -background white -gravity center -extent 600x400 +repage null: PAiVp.png -gravity center -layers composite -layers optimize JN6W6_PAiVp_2.gif
```

[modified by simply cropping using -extent](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/layers_composite/JN6W6_PAiVp_2.gif)

If you want it resized and then cropped,

```
convert JN6W6.gif -coalesce -resize 600x400^ -gravity center -crop 600x400+0+0 +repage null: PAiVp.png -gravity center -layers composite -layers optimize JN6W6_PAiVp_3.gif
```

[modified by resizing and cropping](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/layers_composite/JN6W6_PAiVp_2.gif)

The null: is needed in this processing as a separator.

See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#composite

If using Imagemagick 7, replace convert with magick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's working but size of image is also like gif size. I want to get 600x400 like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRKnt.png. Is it possible?

Comment: Your example that you posted for the output was 600x700. So I assumed that was what you wanted. But if you want 600x400, just change my -resize 500x700 to -resize 600x400. Note that the link you post for what you want is only 460x308!

Comment: See my edits if you want it either just cropped or resized and cropped.

Comment: In the example I wanted to show that GIF image should be cut off from above and below to fit in 600x400. But there is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAuQs.gif

Comment: See my edits in my original post that I just made. You said 600x400 but did you really mean 400x600? Your result that you just posted is 286x400. What do  you really want for the output size! Do you want it cropped, resized or resized and cropped. See all 3 in my edits.